# What is the meaning of [0] at end of return statement

Tags: java

```
return getRights(obj, attrs)[0];
```

What is the meaning of the  `[0]` in the above `return` statement?

Comment: The first element in the array. Please consult a book/tutorial/google to learn the basics of the language. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Return element zero -- the first element in the array returned by `getRights`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getRights(...)` returns an array, and you're returning the first item in that array from your method. Note that Java arrays are 0 based, and so the first index of any array will be `[0]`. This method could potentially run into trouble if the array returned by `getRights(...)` is empty and has no elements or if `getRights(...)` could possibly return a null value.

Answer (score 0):

It means the same as...

```
array[] = getRights(obj, attrs);
return array[0];
```

..., which just returns the first element in the array.